# Problem with jQuery append in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, append

Hi guys I am having a very strange problem in ie with the append function. Basicly i retrieve data from an ajax call in xml. Parse the xml into variables then using the each function append to a specific div. Works fine in firefox had to do a work around to get the file to parse in ie. Please note 'ALL WORKS' fine my variables etc. all have values etc.

However when I use the append function some of the text randomly appears outside its containing div see picture below:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e21468dd49.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e21468dd49.png)

As you can see some of the text overflows the container or almost seems to reflect ?
Any way below is a snippet of the code where i make the append: I should also add I am opening this div in a dialog box created with jquery ui - which sets the containing div to display: block - so i am wondering if this is having any effect.

```
$(xml).find("entry").each(function()
{

var $item = $(this);
var title = $item.find("title").text();
var linkN = $item.find("link").attr("href");
var output = "<a href=\"" + linkN + "\" target=\"_self\">" + title + "<\/a>" + "<br />";
$("#notifyBox").append($(output));
$('#notifyBox').show();
});
```

Really hope you guys can help this is the strangest problem I have ever encountered.

Comment: Are you seeing anything odd in the view source?

Comment: no the source looks fine to - had a look in the generated source and all appears to be fine. all tags are closed properly etc. just really hard to resolve as can't seem any obvious problems.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I always use single quotes for setting String items in JavaScript.  This leaves you free to use double quotes when dynamically constructing markup and removes the headaches of having to escape everything. Just a little tip. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems a single float on the containing box (float: left) - was causing the issue - pesky ie - anyway hope this helps someone if they have the same problem. Thanks to Nick Craver hope helped me re-factor my code a bit - cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$(xml).find("entry").each(function()
{
  var $item = $(this);
  var title = $item.find("title").text();
  var linkN = $item.find("link").attr("href");
  var output = "<a href='" + linkN + "' target='_self'>" + title + "</a><br />";
  $("#notifyBox").append($(output)).show();
});
```

I believe your `<\/a>` is causing the issue, no need to escape the forward slash, browser is seeing it as an unclosed element.

Comment: Cheers Nick, did'nt make any difference however thanks to your suggestion my code is a bit more stream line - which is always postive. thanks for your input

Comment: @jonathan - Can you post the html markup?  Would help in figuring this out

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this:

```
var a = '<span>Attachment: '+Filedata.substr(Filedata.lastIndexOf('\\')+1).toLowerCase()+'</span>';
var b = '<span ><a href="#" class="remove_link" style="cursor:pointer; ">Remove</a></span></br></br>';
                var c = a+' '+b; // use instead of append
                $('div.attach_file').hide();
                $('div.Multi_Attach_file').show().html(c); // display c
```